# Laravel | groupBy returning as object

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to use a Laravel collection to return a `groupBy` as an array. However, it always seems to be returned as an object no matter what. I have tried to do `$posts->groupBy('category')->toArray()` but this seems to still return as an object. I have also tried `$posts->groupBy('category')->all()` and still it is returning as an object.

I don't know if this is something to do with Laravel returning methods within the routes, but I need this to return as an array.

Here is the code:

```php
public function getFeatures($id)
{
    return Feature::query()->get()->groupBy('category')->toArray();
}
```

The actual code is working fine and I'm getting results back but it just doesn't seem to be converting to an array. Thanks.

Comment: What is your use case? Do you need them converted to array to return it to a view or through an API?

Comment: Can you add a `dd(...)` of your output?

Comment: @Jonathon the `dd()` actually says that it is an array. Does the response convert to an object by default?

Comment: Can you show the output in your question, either by adding a screenshot or pasting it in there? Do you get any errors or anything or is it just that you need an array? Do you need each item within the outer array to also be an array too?

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that if you're outputting this as JSON, an associative array in PHP will be represented as an object in JSON. In Javascript/JSON an array is sequential and numerically indexed, an object allows for other types keys (but doesn't guarantee order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading your comment on other answer, I realized what you mean.

> Hi @HCK, thanks for the answer. The `->toArray()` method doesn't seem to work and still returns it like `{ "category_1": [], "category_2": [] }` whereas I need it to do `["category_1": [], "category_2": []]`

First, this answer is based on a guess that you are doing something like this on your controller (you didn't posted the controller code):

```
return reponse()->json($theResponseFromGetFeaturesMethod);
```

Since inside php the `$theResponseFromGetFeaturesMethod` variable contains an dictionary array (something like `["key"=>"value]`), when you convert it to a JSON, you will notice that this "conversion" happens.

This happens because Javascript arrays (and JSON) doesn't support dictionary arrays. See this sample on javascript console:

```
> var a = [];
  undefined
> a['key'] = "value"
  "value"
> a
  > key: "value"
    length: 0
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

Note that the `a` still have a length of zero, but it now have an `key` property.

This happens because almost everything on javascript is actually an object. So the array is a special kind of object that have `push`, `pop` and many other array methods. Doing `array[] = 'somevalue'` is actually a shortcut to `array.push('somevalue')`.

So, the behavior that you are observing is right, the `toArray()` method work as expected, and the JSON conversion too.

---

Another weird behavior is when you try to convert this PHP array to an JSON:

```
[
     0 => 'a'
     1 => 'b'
     9 => 'c'
]
```

You will note that in  this case, PHP will convert this array to an object too. The result in JSON will be:

```
{
    "0": "a",
    "1": "b",
    "2": "c"
}
```

This is also the expected behavior, since the JSON syntax doesn't support defining the index for a value.

Comment: Hmm, the only thing is I need to map this response in React. I am really trying to avoid having to do something like `Object.keys` do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You can make your response looks something like: `[ {"category": 1, "items": [...]}, {"category": 2, "items": [...]} ]` so you can use map (or filter, if you need a specific category) on this response

Answer (score 1):

When doing a query to get (possibly) several items using Eloquent, [Laravel will always return](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#retrieving-models) an instance of the [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-collections) class that contains all the model objects. If you need them converted to array to use them in a view you could `compact` the elements. `compact` will make an associative array of the elements of the collection:

```php
public function getFeatures($id)
{
    $features = Feature::all();

    return view('my_cool_view', compact($features));
}
```

On the other hand, if you need them converted to array to return them through an API, Laravel convert the response to JSON by default:

```php
public function getFeatures($id)
{
    return Feature::all();
}
```

Now, if you somehow need the collection converted to an array, just use `toArray()` like you indicated:

```php
public function getFeatures($id)
{
    $collection_of_features = Feature::all();

    $array_of_features = $collection_of_features->toArray();

    // use it for wherever you want.

}
```

Comment: Hi @HCK, thanks for the answer. The `->toArray()` method doesn't seem to work and still returns it like `{ "category_1": [], "category_2": []  }` whereas I need it to do `["category_1": [], "category_2": []]`